# Converting PHP query to PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

I have some php that is receiving a variable from jquery and querying the DB. I recently learned that I need to use PDO to prevent SQL Injections and such so I have been trying to convert my query to it. I am new at php anyway so this is turning out to be more difficult than I thought (even though all the articles I read looked quite straightforward)...The DB connection is working and `'name'` is receiving the right value but it is not updating the page like it used to. I am guessing it has to do with my loop that contains the `json_encode`. Below is my old php and then my attempt at turning it into PDO format.

Old PHP:

```
$dbstylename = $_POST['name'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM style where stylename like '$dbstylename'");
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo json_encode($array);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

New PDO attempt:

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

try {
    $dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbhost;', $user, $pass);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    #Prepare the query
    $dbstylename = $_POST['name'];
    $result = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM style where stylename like :dbstylename');
    #bind
    $result->bindParam(':dbstylename', $dbstylename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    #execute
    if ($result->execute(array($dbstylename))) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            json_encode($row);
        }
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

================UPDATE==============================

In addition to @MadaraUchiha great answer and follow up help I had to change my jQuery from this (which worked before PDO):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'name' : target},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var styleid = data[0];
        var stylename = data[1];
        var stylecss = data[2];
        $('#codeTest').html("<b>id: </b><br />"+styleid+"<br /><b> stylename: </b><br />"+stylename+"<br /><b> stylecss: </b><br />"+stylecss);
    }
});
```

To this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'name' : target},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var styleid = data.styleid;
        var stylename = data.stylename;
        var stylecss = data.stylecss;
        $('#codeTest').html("<b>id: </b><br />"+styleid+"<br /><b> stylename: </b><br />"+stylename+"<br /><b> stylecss: </b><br />"+stylecss);
    }
});
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Your PDO version is not `echo`ing the encoded result. (Though if you want to only echo one row, you don't need the `while` loop.)

Comment: @Ibu I think it is querying fine but I don't think I am bring back the results correctly so that the jQuery can update the page..does that make sense? =\

Comment: @DCoder I didn't think I needed the loop since I didn't use it before (because I only return 1 row at a time) but the closest article I found used it so I figured it wouldn't actually hurt since it will only return a single row anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with this, it's great that you're working on improving from the old ext/mysql to PDO. Well done!

Well, first, you don't need to check for errors! Since you've set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, an Exception would be thrown if there's an error! so your if statement on

```
if ($result->execute(array($dbstylename))) {
```

Is redundant.

Second, since you've already bound the parameter with `bindParam`, passing it again with the array is also redundant.

Lastly, if you only expect one result, you can drop the `while` loop, or even use `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to fetch all of the result into a single array.

---

Now for the real problem, you aren't echoing the result of `json_encode()`, like you used to in the first script (You're just calling it without doing anything with the result).

Corrected code, with all of the above taken into account:

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

try {

    $dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbhost;', $user, $pass);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    #Prepare the query
    $dbstylename = $_POST['name'];
    $result = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM style where stylename like :dbstylename');
    #bind
    $result->bindParam(':dbstylename', $dbstylename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    #execute
    $result->execute();
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($row);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Other than that, you're PDO code is flawless, keep it up!

Comment: Also passing an array to execute is redundant, since it was bound earlier.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked on my friends server that I was originally testing on. Unfortunately, when I move it to mine I am getting a Response back of `ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known` so I guess I need to look into that now..sigh..lol it s never ending battle!

Comment: @tehaaron: It probably means that your `$dbhost` is wrong. (Maybe you want `localhost`?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it is `localhost` and all the settings worked before I enabled PDO. So I am guessing I need to check some ini files or socket files or something?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I got the connection fixed for pdo on my server and it looks like I have a problem now. Instead of passing `name: test1` it is passing `test1: undefined` it looks like it is taking the value and making it the key?

Comment: @tehaaron: Could you paste your code and give us a link here?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha javascript: http://pastebin.com/tzHCRiJq  --- php: http://pastebin.com/ZDdQvcqw  --- The php is just like yours above.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @tehaaron: Hmm, try `var_dump()`ing the `$_POST` array to see if the value is correctly passed to PHP.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha so I dar var_dumps on all my variables and they all are correct! even the data in `$row` and `$results` no idea why the jquery is writing back undefined....gonna have to mess with it now..I think

Comment: @tehaaron: [Let's continue this discussion at chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha so I corrected a slight typo and it made console.log(data) work as expected however it appears to be returning as 1 object/string..definitely not as an array like it was prior to this PDO fiasco.

Comment: @tehaaron: That's expected. You can now save this object into a variable, and use its values as you need.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I got it all sorted out and added my jQuery changes to the original post. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @tehaaron: Just a note, you can **still** fetch the result as a numerated array, using `PDO::FETCH_NUMERIC` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha after I posted the changes I read the manual a bit more and figured out I could change to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` to cover both bases. I posted it in an answer at the bottom. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also sequence of json encoded strings with array elements are not equal to hole json encoded array. Replace while loop with

```
echo json_encode($result->fetchAll());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my original post I mentioned my jQuery change. However, I read up a bit more about PDO in the manual (specifically: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and found that if I changed `$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` from @MadaraUchiha answer to `$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);` I could keep my original jQuery that used the array/bracket notation.